# What is the function of varistor in this design

Tags: snubber, varistor

Came across this on internet. The description mentioned this module help prevent relay stick to the contact. Please explain why varistor need to be included in the design if it is to connect in parallel to relay contact.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are driving an inductive load, and abruptly stopping current through it by opening relay contacts, the induced back-EMF voltage which happens due to the collapsing magnetic field is in theory infinite. The capacitor has a maximum voltage limit, and so does the resistor. So to protect the RC snubber, a TVS is used to clamp excess voltage not handled by the RC snubber network.